# Provide column and row names for data.frame in 1 line

Tags: r

I have a vector of rownames (x) and I want to name my columns (2) "A" and "B".

I want to do it in one line of code - data.frame(row.names = x, "A", "B").

Please advise what I am doing wrong? Should I use multiple lines of code for this?

Comment: rownames(df) <- c("A", "B")

Comment: How many rows in your data.frame?

Comment: if you have the names in a vector then, `rownames(df) <- x`

Comment: Steve, look into using `dimnames` if you really want a one liner.  Otherwise look at my now deleted answer.

Comment: Basically what I want is to specify column names A and B, row names (I have 6 row names) and fill it on demand using for loop.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you be so kind and post an example? Where do I put the dimnames? In the data.frame?
data.frame(dimnames(rownames, c("A","B"))?

Comment: Sorry for my comment earlier, you can do `dimnames(df) <- list(rownames, c("A","B"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are after. But you can re-name row and column names as below using `dimnames` - this can be extended to multidimensional arrays as well.

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1:3), B=c(4:6))

dimnames(df)[[1]] <- row_names_vector
dimnames(df)[[2]] <- col_names_vector
```

Other option is

```
   rownames(df) <-  row_names_vector
   colnames(df) <-  col_names_vector
```

One line

```
dimnames(df) <- list(row_names_vector, col_names_vector)
```

Example

```
row_names_vector <- letters[1:3]
col_names_vector <- letters[1:2]
dimnames(df) <- list(row_names_vector, col_names_vector)
```

Comment: You can do that in one line, like the OP asks.

Comment: I didn't actually realize what he meant. :)

Comment: Again, I have meant that I want to do it within data.frame() function in one line but thank you very very much for such detailed professional answer!